# Success Message Not Showing ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Trying to display Success message in form of a panel when action is successful.

The message shows immediately the View is loaded and not after the operation has been done.

The code in View is below

```
@if (TempData["Success"] != null)
            {
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <p><strong>Success:</strong> @TempData["Success"].ToString()</p>
                </div>
            }
```

The code inside the controller is below. Am i missing anything?

```
TempData["Success"] = "Account Debited Successfully.";
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

I also tried the below in the View, Still same issue. I have an Ajax call on the page already

```
@if (ViewBag.Message != null)  
{  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        window.onload = function () {  
            alert("@ViewBag.Message");  
        };  
    </script>  
}
```

Comment: The only thing missing in this code is where this temp data was assigned after redirect. see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063952/viewbag-arrives-empty/57066680#57066680

Comment: @Bosco, It is the same thing I am doing. I have checked you answer. Can you point where I am missing it here?

Comment: Did you look at the part where you assign the `TempData["Success"]` to a `ViewBag["Success"]`?